# Does multivariate polynomial over a finite field always have a solution (in the field)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields

Let $K = F_{p^e}$ be a finite field. Say I have a single polynomial $f \in K[x_1,\ldots, x_n]$ of degree $d$.

Under what conditions on $n$ and $d$ can I claim that a root to $f$ always exists? In other words, do there exist polynomials over finite fields with an arbitrary number of variables and bounded degree that have no roots in the field?

If a root exists, can I compute it efficiently?

Comment: $\Bbb Z_{p^e}$ is not a field.

Comment: Using $\mathbb{F}_{p^e}$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}/p^e$, there are very few cases when you can be sure of a root in the field itself.  For example, when $n=1$, the only case where you are guaranteed a root in the field is when $d=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it with $n$ and $d$ alone, unless $d=1$ (which is a hyperplane and so is easy to find all solutions).

For example, we know $\mathbb{F}_{p^{2e}}$ is a degree 2 extension of $\mathbb{F}_{p^e}$, so there is an irreducible quadratic $x^2+ax+b$ in $\mathbb{F}_{p^e}[x]$.  Consequently,
$$
(a_1x_1+\dots+a_nx_n)^2+a(a_1x_1+\dots+a_nx_n)+b=0
$$
has no solutions for all $(a_1,\dots,a_n)\in\mathbb{F}_{p^e}^n-\{(0,\dots,0\}$.  Similar construction gives no $d>1$ can guarantees the existence of a zero regardless of how large $n$ is.

Note that this doesn't contradict [Chavelley-Warning theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chevalley%E2%80%93Warning_theorem), since the number of zeros, $0$, is divisible by $p$.

Answer (score 2):

The polynomial
$$
f=(x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_n)^2−k
$$
where $k$ is not a quadratic residue modulo $q$ has no roots in  the finite field $\Bbb F_{q}$.

Answer (score -1):

Even with $n=1$, this would mean the field is algebraically closed, and an algebraically closed field cannot be finite.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the very helpful responses. Do there exist conditions on the polynomial that if imposed, guarantee that a solution exists (and can be computed efficiently)?

Comment: As far as I know, even  for single variable polynomials, there's no general rule.